# Нужно ли создавать для каждого ajax запроса отдельный php файл?

Tags: php, ajax

На странице php имеется несколько ajax запросов (на разные данные из БД). Необходимо ли для каждого запроса создавать отдельный php файл - обработчик, указываемый в url, или можно обойтись одним файлом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от объема запросов, преобразований и личного порядка в коде. В вашем случае можно сделать например так:

```
$q['users'] = "SELECT FROM 'users' ... ";
$q['news'] = "SELECT FROM 'news' ... ";
...

if ($_GET['query'] && $q[$_GET['query']]) {
    $result = mysql_query($q[$_GET['query']]);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете правильную архитектуру с использованием контроллеров и роутинга, например MVC, создание файла на каждый запрос не требуется, требуется лишь создание файла на группу запросов.

Рекомендую Вам посмотреть в сторону PHP фреймворков (напр. Lavarel) или микрофреймворков, на которых у вас не будет проблем в разработке приложений с правильной архитектурой. Создание отдельных файлов на запрос подход, который влечет за собой **кучу проблем** в поддержке проекта. Потратите время на изучение, но дальнейшая разработка будет проще и эффективнее.